# PEP8, invalid escape sequence, o que tem de errado com o código

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo a usar o webscraping no Python (versão 3.7).

Estou tratando com Expressões regulares e ao escrever este código:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/pages3.html')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bsObj.findAll('img', {'src': re.compile("\.\./img/gifts/img.*\.jpg")})
for image in images:
    print(image['src'])
```

Precisamente na seguinte linha `images = bsObj.findAll('img', {'src': re.compile("\.\./img/gifts/img.*\.jpg")})` o pycharm me notifica com a mensagem 'PEP8 invalid escape sequence'.

Gostaria que me ajudassem a entender e consertar o possível erro.

Comment: Tenta formatar melhor seu código pra facilitar nossa leitura, vou responder abaixo a minha solução

Answer (score 2):

Basta "escapar" os "escapes", assim:

```
re.compile("\\.\\./img/gifts/img.*\\.jpg")
```

Ou pode usar o `r"..."` como explicado em: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

```
re.compile(r"\.\./img/gifts/img.*\.jpg")
```

PS: o ponto `.` em regex significa qualquer caractere (ele não é o mesmo `[\s\S]`), portanto somente isto `r"../img/gifts/img.*.jpg"` pode falhar sua lógica, já que coisas assim seriam aceitas:

```
ab/img/gifts/img1000ajpg
fo/img/gifts/img2000Zjpg
```

E provavelmente não é o que deseja

Veja que continua a funcionar: https://repl.it/@inphinit/regex-escape-python

Comment: Obrigadão, irmão...Foi muito útil a solução!

Comment: @Sthino_IV blz. marque a resposta como correta por favor. Se não sabe como fazer leia as instruções em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635